# Postmates - Security CAPTCHA Error in Postmates API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postmates

I need to integrate Postmates API in my ruby on rails application.
I am constantly receiving an error of CAPTCHA when I hit the delivery quotes API 
The request is `https://api.postmates.com/v1/customers/my_customer_id/delivery_quotes`

error is

> “Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you
>   temporary access to the web property.”

Do anybody have a solution for this error? how can get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing this issue, you need to whitelist your IP address on postmates then only you can use postmates api without any security captcha.

you can contact any technical person from postmates support and white list your IP address.

Comment: I tried VPN connection and working perfect in postman.

Comment: It's better to whitelist domain rather than using VPN IMO :)

Comment: how can whitelist in postmate? any tutorial ?

Comment: We have to send mail to the support team. they will whitelist it.